# Parse not retrieving array of objects

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am storing an array of Javascript objects in Parse under the name 'AcceptedInvitees'. The objects each have two values; an example entry is:

```
[{"id":"QpAETvSYaB","type":"Requested"},{"id":"Ojjp3TdmTM","type":"unknown"},{"id":"STAUUgVxJp","type":"unknown"},{"id":"AXBC5iZvKQ","type":"unknown"},{"id":"YixKjqrjTM","type":"unknown"},{"id":"b2YwmMcO6n","type":"unknown"},{"id":"DjZePR0Wif","type":"unknown"},{"id":"94Harl1hxm","type":"unknown"},{"id":"1bOE07B0C8","type":"unknown"}]
```

I am trying to retrieve this value using .get("AcceptedInvitees"), but I am being returned an array of empty objects. For example, retrieving the above entry gives me

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

This is the specific code I am using to query the data. All the other fields are being retrieved without a problem, but printing node.children gives me the above.

```
var query = new Parse.Query("UserInvite");
query.include("AcceptedInvitees");
query.get(id, {
    success: function (user) {
        node.name = user.get("name");
        node.TotalInvitees = user.get("TotalInvitees");
        node.type = type;
        node.children = user.get("AcceptedInvitees");
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you show more code on how you're querying the data ?

Comment: added the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

`Parse.Query` expects `Parse.Object`. Therefore, do as following:

```
var UserInvite = Parse.Object.extend("UserInvite");
var id = 'someUserInviteId';
var query = new Parse.Query(UserInvite);
query.include("AcceptedInvitees");
query.get(id, {
  success: function(obj) {
    console.log(obj.toJSON());
  },
  error: function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried that - the array is still an empty set as above.

Comment: Do your parse object has relationships  ?

Comment: You should add relation while saving objects if they are supposed to have relation. Check this out: https://www.parse.com/questions/how-can-i-add-objects-to-a-relation